# A Farewell Message From My Toys!

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle, visual

Remember the day when you grew up and didn't want to play anymore with toys?

Well, I remember the same happening with me. But, well, my toys were smart. And may be they left a goodbye message for me.

```
             **               **             **               **                                    
            |  |             |  |           |  |             |  |
          *      *         *      *       *      *         *      *                                                                                                                                                     
        *          *     *          *   *          *     *          *                                                                                                                                                                       
        *    E     *     *    Q     *   *    Q     *     *    X     *                   
         *        *       *        *     *        *       *        *
           * ___ *          * ___ *        * ___ *          * ___ *              
              |                |              |                |


             **               **             **               **                                    
            |  |             |  |           |  |             |  |
          *      *         *      *       *      *         *      *                                                                                                                                                     
        *          *     *          *   *          *     *          *                                                                                                                                                                       
        *    P     *     *    K     *   *    L     *     *    X     *                   
         *        *       *        *     *        *       *        *
          * ___ *          * ___ *         * ___ *          * ___ *             
             |                |               |                |

             **               **             **               **                                    
            |  |             |  |           |  |             |  |
          *      *         *      *       *      *         *      *                                                                                                                                                     
        *          *     *          *   *          *     *          *                                                                                                                                                                       
        *    D     *     *    C     *   *    T     *     *    Z     *                   
         *        *       *        *     *        *       *        *
           * ___ *          * ___ *        * ___ *         * ___ *             
              |                |              |               |

             **               **             **               **               **                                 
            |  |             |  |           |  |             |  |             |  |
          *      *         *      *       *      *         *      *         *      *                                                                                                                                                
        *          *     *          *   *          *     *          *     *          *                                                                                                                                                                  
        *    N     *     *    H     *   *    I     *     *    Y     *     *    T     *                 
         *        *       *        *     *        *       *        *       *        *
          * ___ *           * ___ *        * ___ *          * ___ *          * ___ *          
             |                 |              |                |                |
```

**Can you help me find the message my toys left?**

Comment: you have a fetish for ASCII drawings, don't you? :D

Comment: @Marius Not the way you have for *Magento* :-)

Comment: Touche! Fair enough.

Comment: Those are some nice looking radishes

Comment: @n_palum If those were radishes, this puzzle would have been unsolvable :-)

Comment: WELL, i think i'll wait for someone to solve this, i give up. I am not good enough to understand the logic behind your ASCII drawings

Comment: @FrancescoRoggia I'll add a hint or a tag if it remains unsolved :-) Try to identify the toy and you should get it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your toys were saying

> DON'T KEEP US IN ATTIC

The letters EQQX PKLX DCTZ NHIYT when

> Rotated backwards in the alphabet by 1, 2, ... 17 spaces respectively e.g. 
>  
>  (1) E → **D**, (2) Q → **O**, (3) Q → **N**, (4) X → **T**  ...
>
>  And so on until the last letter (17) T → **C**

And the toys were

> Rotating spinning [tops](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Top)

Comment: The toys applied a rot-n to each of their letters as per their positions! Nice work :-) +15

Comment: Thanks @Techidiot for this well designed series of ASCII puzzles - I've enjoyed the previous ones too - and your explanation above is neater!